# How can I throw a ClassCastException from inside a generic wrapper or at compile time

Tags: java, android, generics, exception, throw

This problem occurs specifically in Android(but not limited to). So we create 2 wrappers, but the Object assignment is done inside (if I were to create wrapper `wrongWrapper` using `new AWrapper<>((B1) findObjectStupid(false));` it would give a `ClassCastException` immediately instead of later)

```
class A {}
class B1 extends A {}
class B2 extends A {}

class AWrapper<T extends A> {
    T a;

    AWrapper(T a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    AWrapper(boolean b) {
        this((T) findObjectStupid(b));  //this throws a ClassCastException only if findObjectStupid(b) is not an A class
    }

    public T getA() {
        return a;
    }
}

<T extends A> T findObjectStupid(boolean b) { /in android this method mimics the findViewById(int id) 
    if (b) {
    return (T) new B1();
    } else {
    return (T) new B2();
    }
}

void main() {
    AWrapper<B1> rightWrapper = new AWrapper<>(true);
    AWrapper<?> dontCareWrapper = new AWrapper<>(true); 
    AWrapper<B1> wrongWrapper = new AWrapper<>(false); //should give ClassCastException now, but doesn't
    //AWrapper<B1> wrongWrapper = new AWrapper<>((B1) findObjectStupid(false)); //this way ClassCastException is thrown immediately

    B1 rightObject = rightWrapper.getA();
    A dontCareObject = dontCareWrapper.getA(); // we know we can cast it to B1 and it would work
    B1 wrongObject = wrongWrapper.getA(); //gives ClassCastException now, not good!
}
```

Obviously the wrapper is designed to have methods that use the Object as A, the only time T type is really needed is when `getA()` is called making this wrapper become problematic if the programmer in question forgets to call that specific method today and the bug may remain hidden for a long while until it is actually needed.

How can the above wrapper be modified to throw a ClassCastException when created and not when `getA()` is called?

Comment: You can't. The field in the class is erased to `A`.

Comment: @michael deep down i know that, but also no similar question for this situation compelled me to ask it for future people that want to implement this sort of thing

Answer (score 0):

There is only one way to unerase the generic wrapper, create a field that says exactly what type should be inside it, obviously this implies a small performance drop but guarantees type safety. Is it worth it? Probably not.

```
class AWrapper<T extends A> {
    T a;
    Class<? super T> tClass; //new
    //Class<T> tClass; //or like this if exact match is needed

    AWrapper(T a, Class<? super T> tClass) { //edited
    //AWrapper(T a, Class<T> tClass) { //or like this if exact match is needed
        if (a.getClass().isInstance(tClass)) { //new
        //if (a.getClass().equals(tClass)){ //or like this if exact match is needed
            throw new ClassCastException("Object being wrapped is not of good type, the cause and solution is simply a programmer declared this generic type of an uncompatible type, this exception is designed to reduce runtime ClassCastExceptions by throwing them not at compiletime(impossible) but as soon as possible"); //new
        }
        this.a = a;
        this.tClass = tClass; //new
    }

    AWrapper(boolean b, Class<T> tClass) { //edited
        this((T) findObjectStupid(b), tClass); //edited
    }

    public T getA() {
        return a;
    }
}

<T extends A> T findObjectStupid(boolean b) {
    if (b) {
        return (T) new B1();
    } else {
        return (T) new B2();
    }
}

void main() {
    AWrapper<B1> rightWrapper = new AWrapper<>(true, B1.class); //edited
    AWrapper<B1> wrongWrapper = new AWrapper<>(false, B1.class);  //edited, now this throws exception just like we hoped

    B1 rightObject = rightWrapper.getA();
    B1 wrongObject = wrongWrapper.getA(); //never gets here
}
```

In the above code the class is saved so that later the T object can be reassigned, but if the assigning is only done once in the constructor then the `Class<? super T> tClass;` line can be removed entirely. By removing this line obviously all the typesafety with none of the performance drop (except the actual if statement).